# How to format command line input in C

Tags: c, argv

I'm trying to do the parentheses balance problem and adjust [the following](https://www.faceprep.in/c/balanced-parentheses-using-stack/) code to work with command-line input (argc/argv), but I can't figure out how to properly push variables to the stack and do comparisons between the stack and parentheses.

```
balance.c: In function 'push':
balance.c:16:18: error: expected expression before 'char'
     len = strlen(char[i]);
                  ^~~~
balance.c:19:9: error: expected expression before 'char'
         char[i]=other[i];
         ^~~~
balance.c:25:22: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         s.stk[s.top] = other;
                      ^
balance.c: In function 'main':
balance.c:55:33: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
                 if(s.stk[s.top] == "(")
```

I was hoping to get advice on how to properly format cmd input so I would be able to make comparisons. I've adjusted some of them by using strcmp, but am not sure how to move forward.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 20

struct stack
{
    char stk[MAX];
    int top;
}s;

void push(char* item)
{
    int len;
    int i;
    len = strlen(char[i]);
    char other [len];
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        char[i]=other[i];
    if (s.top == (MAX - 1))
        printf ("Stack is Full\n");
    else
    {
        s.top = s.top + 1; // Push the char and increment top
        s.stk[s.top] = other;
    }}

void pop()
{
    if (s.top == - 1)
    {
        printf ("Stack is Empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        s.top = s.top - 1; // Pop the char and decrement top
    }}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    s.top = -1;
    for(i = 0;i < argc;i++)
    {
        if((strcmp(argv[i],"(")==0) || (strcmp(argv[i],"[")==0) || (strcmp(argv[i],"{")==0))
        {
            push(argv[i]); // Push the open bracket
            continue;
        }
        else if((strcmp(argv[i],")")==0) || (strcmp(argv[i],"]")==0) || (strcmp(argv[i],"}")==0)) // If a closed bracket is encountered
        {
            if((strcmp(argv[i],")")==0))
            {
                if(s.stk[s.top] == "(")
                {
                    pop(); // Pop the stack until closed bracket is found
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\nUNBALANCED EXPRESSION\n");
                    break;
                }}
            if((strcmp(argv[i],"]")==0))
            {
                if(s.stk[s.top] == "[")
                {
                    pop(); // Pop the stack until closed bracket is found
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\nUNBALANCED EXPRESSION\n");
                    break;
                }}
            if((strcmp(argv[i],"}")==0))
            {
                if(s.stk[s.top] == "{")
                {
                    pop(); // Pop the stack until closed bracket is found
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\nUNBALANCED EXPRESSION\n");
                    break;
                }}}}
    if(s.top == -1)
    {
        printf("\nBALANCED EXPRESSION\n"); // Finally if the stack is empty, display that the expression is balanced
    }}
```

Comment: It seems you should use [`strcpy()` (or safer `strncpy()`)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) function in your `push()` function.

Comment: `len = strlen(char[i]);` => `len=strlen(item);`?

Comment: `char[i]=other[i];` => `other[i] = item[i];`? ...

Comment: @MikeCAT thank you, will try!

Comment: @Mathieu whoops. Sorry, missed that before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

`len = strlen(char[i]);` 
Does not mean nothing. If you want to get the size of `item`, you must write:
`len = strlen(item);`

---

```
char other [len];
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    char[i]=other[i];
```

You try to copy the uninitiated data of `other` into...`item`?
In that case, you should have written

```
char other [len+1];
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    other[i] = item[i];
other[len] = '\0'; // do not forget the final character of a NULL terminated string.
```

or

```
char other [len+1];
strcpy(other, item);
```

**But**, since `other` will be use in the stack, so outside of `push`, it can't be internal to `push`, you have to reserve some memory with `malloc` or friend functions. In that case, you don't need `len` and a simple

```
char *other = strdup(item); //( ~ malloc + strcpy in one function)
```

whould be enough.

(re)**But** given the stack and the code using it, it seems you only stack single characters. In that case, you could simplify `push` to:

```
void push(char* item)
{
    if (s.top == (MAX - 1))
        printf ("Stack is Full\n");
    else
    {
        s.top = s.top + 1; // Push the char and increment top
        s.stk[s.top] = item[0]; 
    }
}
```

---

On one other side, your main function seems complicated using `strcmp` where simple `char` comparison would suffice:

```
(strcmp(argv[i],"(")==0)
```

can be written

```
( argv[i][0] == '(' )
```

And you stack character checking is wrong:

```
            if(s.stk[s.top] == "(")
```

should be writteng

```
            if(s.stk[s.top] == '(')
```

Moreover, your code could have a real interest using `switch/case`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    s.top = -1;
    for(i = 0;i < argc;i++)
    {
        switch(argv[i][0]) {
            case '(':
            case '[':
                push(argv[i]); // Push the open bracket
                break;
            case ')':
                if(s.stk[s.top] == '(') // note what happend in s.top is -1?
                    pop()
                else
                    printf("\nUNBALANCED EXPRESSION\n");
                    return;
            case ']':
                if(s.stk[s.top] == ']') // note what happend in s.top is -1?
                    pop()
                else
                    printf("\nUNBALANCED EXPRESSION\n");
                    return 0;

        }
    }
       
    if(s.top == -1)
    {
        printf("\nBALANCED EXPRESSION\n"); // Finally if the stack is empty, display that the expression is balanced
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mathieu, this is very thorough! I'm super new to C and programming in general, so this is very valuable advice